# Make element absolute, but do not change its position on the screen

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have an element that is relative positioned on the page, relative to its parent element.

How can I make this element absolute with jQuery.css, but without changing the actual position on the screen? It should stay in the same place, and it should be absolute relative to the document body

$.css('position', 'absolute') will re-position the element

If it can't be done, how can I change the x,y position of this element on the screen, relative to the document body (or the browser screen)?

Comment: Why? The only usecases I can think of for this would be better served with `position: relative`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't know why you would do this, but check out [`offset`](http://api.jquery.com/offset/). You'd do something like:

```
var offset = $('#element').offset();
$('#element').css('position', 'absolute')
    .css('top', offset.top)
    .css('left', offset.left);
```